# Jquery-Mobile taphold specific area on image

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an image and I want to make taphold events for specific areas of the image.  The image scales to 100% width of the page.

Is there any possible way in Jquery-Mobile to to get this done?  I've been looking everywhere and can't seem to find a way of getting around this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to use image mapping to solve this problem.